# Cannot create article categories in joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I use joomla 3.1.5, php 5.4.20

When my php was 5.3.x everything was fine but after upgrading php to 5.4.20 i cannot create new article categories!
I get Internal Server Error:

`The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

This is not an issue with `.htaccess` (don't have any) or permissions(checked it a lot of times).

Strange thing is that when i enable debug system in global configuration the problem is solved!!! When disabling debug system problem comes back.

This only happens in joomla 3.x installations. I use the same server with joomla 2.5.x and it works fine.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a bug. Check bug reports and forums

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Joomla forum ? PHP 5.4 is not used much and the Joomla 3.1.5 might have some modules that are not compatible with the PHP 5.4.

Comment: I did ask the same question in joomla forums. I was told to check if the problem is solved with the svn version of joomla 3.2. But i cannot even install this version.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share the fix to this problem. EAccelerator was causing the issue after disabling it everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the main problem is with the PHP version.

To be able to Create New Categories do this :

1. In your joomla "Control Panel" page, this is usually the first page when you log in,  scroll down and under CONFIGURATION click "Global."
2. In the new page for "Global" that open opens, look for "Default Editor", if you have not changed it before it's value should be "Editor - TinyMCE". Change that to "Editor-None." --Note that for now you will not be able to use the default WYSIWYG.
3. Click "Save & Close".
4. Now go back to the page for creating new categories, refresh it and create your categories.
5. To have access again to the default  WYSIWYG, after you have finished creating your categories, go back to "Global " and change the editor back to TinyMCE.

Good Coding.